# I need my swiftui iOS application to stay always on

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have been searching for examples on this and it probably is easy to solve. I would like my app to say 'always on', after a couple of minutes the screen grays out and then turns off but I need the app to be 'always on' until I manually minimize it or close it.

Thank you for your help,

Ignacio

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [isIdleTimerDisabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623070-isidletimerdisabled)

```
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
```